# Why is this considered borrowed

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrow

I've been learning rust and I've been trying to learn the borrow checker works but i've come across this two examples that i don't understand why only one of those is considered borrowed :

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("aa ab");

    let y = first_word(&x);

    x.clear(); //Error cannot borrow X

    println!("{y}");


}

//Returns an i32 reference
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &i32 {
    return &32;
}
```

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("aa ab");

    let y = first_word(&x);

    x.clear(); //Everything is fine

    println!("{y}");


}

//Returns an i32
fn first_word(s: &String) -> i32 {
    return 32;
}
```

Is it possible for someone to explain why only the second one works?

Comment: This might be confusing because of lifetime elision. `first_word(s: &String) -> &i32` is actually `first_word<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a i32` so `x` is borrowed as long as `y` is alive in your first example, but not your second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust does not look into function to understand how they work on the outside. The function signature must contain all necessary information.

The signature `fn first_word(s: &String) -> &i32` says "takes a reference to a string" (by the way, it's practically never useful to have a `&String`, always use `&str` instead), and return a reference to an int. But Rust also needs lifetime information, i.e. some bounds on how long the things behind the references live.

The way this works is a very simple process called [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). For "takes a reference, returns a reference", the sane assumption is that whatever is returned is somehow related to what's passed in, so the full signature becomes `fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a i32`.

This means that the compiler, when it sees a call to `first_word`, will assume that as long as you keep the returned reference around (the `y` in your code), the thing passed in is still borrowed.